# Stored procedure to handle empty sets

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I make a stored procedure to print a specific message if an empty set wa returned by the query?

Comment: If an empy set was returned by *which* query *are you referring to?* You can generate arbitrary record sets, exceptions, and warnings from stored procedures, and one of those things is probably what you mean by "print" ... so please be more specific about specifically what you are trying to do and when, and under what condition.

Comment: We have an authentication database so if we make a select and the user/password is wrong or doesn't exist we want that case to be handled on the level of the database not the application so instead of handling empty set exception using the application we would like to do it using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.5 or 5.6, you can accomplish this with [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).

Simplified example, inside the body of the procedure...

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = input_username AND password = input_password) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'authentication failed.';
ELSE
  -- normal code to select and return the username other info to the caller, etc.
END IF;
```

This will throw an exception:

```
ERROR 1644 (45000): authentication failed.
```

If you wanted to be more specific, you'd need to declare a variable to use a the `MESSAGE_TEXT` and populate it accordingly before calling `SIGNAL` because `SIGNAL` only accepts a variable -- not an expression -- as an argument:

```
DECLARE custom_error TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
...
SET custom_error = LEFT(CONCAT('authentication failed for user ',IFNULL(CONCAT("'",input_username,"'"),'NULL')),128);
...
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = custom_error;
```

Your code would probably take a different approach than `IF ... EXISTS` such as selecting `INTO` a variable and then testing that variable for null and then either returning it to the called with an unbounded `SELECT` or throwing the exception.

The reason for the `LEFT( ...,128)` is that this is the maximum length for an argument to `MESSAGE_TEXT`.  Overrunning it won't hurt anything but you'll end up throwing an error about the invalid argument instead of the error you intended.

For simplicity, the example assumes that the password is in cleartext which obviously wouldn't be the case.